# Bash Backup Script

Tags: bash

The following script closes a virtual machine (which is run in a screen session), waits for the session to close, creates a backup of the VM, and restarts the VM. The shutdown and bootup scripts speak for themselves, but I can post them if necessary. Is there any way to clean up the `sockets_found` function? It seems like there should be an easier way to detect whether or not screen has any open sessions.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=`date '+%Y%m%d'`

# No Sockets found
# There is a screen on
function sockets_found {
    screen -ls | grep "There is a screen on"
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}

function wait_for_sockets_to_close {
    while sockets_found; do
        echo "Waiting for screen to close..."
        sleep 1
    done;
}

echo "Shutdown VM..."
/bin/bash ~/shutdown.sh
wait_for_sockets_to_close
# ensure that the backup directory exists
mkdir -p ~/backup
echo "Copying VM to backup directory..."
cp -Rf ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/ ~/backup/VirtualBox\ VMs${now}/
echo "Booting VM..."
/bin/bash ~/bootup.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be improved and simplified:

> ```
> function sockets_found {
>     screen -ls | grep "There is a screen on"
>     if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
>         return 1
>     else
>         return 0
>     fi
> }
> ```

Like this:

```
function sockets_found {
    screen -ls | grep -q "There is a screen on"
}
```

That is:

- You can remove the `if` statement, as the exit code of `grep` naturally becomes the exit code of the function
- If the exit code of `grep` is greater than 1, the original function exits with 0. That's inappropriate. Such exit codes indicate errors in `grep`, and do not imply that screen sessions exist
- I added the `-q` flag to suppress the output of `grep` in case of success

Other minor things:

- No need for the `;` in `done;`
- It would be better to double-quote `${now}` in the backup target directory to prevent accidental globbing or word splitting, in case you might make a mistake in the syntax of the `date` command
- It would be good to add some blank lines in the last chunk of commands for better readability

Like this:

```
echo "Shutdown VM..."
/bin/bash ~/shutdown.sh

wait_for_sockets_to_close

# ensure that the backup directory exists
mkdir -p ~/backup

echo "Copying VM to backup directory..."
now=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
cp -Rf ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/ ~/backup/VirtualBox\ VMs"${now}"/

echo "Booting VM..."
/bin/bash ~/bootup.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can find if the socket file exists on `/var/run/screen/S-yourname/pid.screenname`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to grep here:

```
screen -ls | grep "There is a screen on"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
```

`Screen -ls` will return with exit code 1 in the case no sockets are found in `/var/run`.

I would run the date command just before the copy is run, in case the sockets close during a date roll and you get the wrong date on your backup.

```
echo "Copying VM to backup directory..."
now=$(date '+%Y%m%d')
cp -Rf ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/ ~/backup/VirtualBox\ VMs${now}/
```

As above use `$(cmd)` notation instead of backtick notation. They achieve the same thing, but `$()` is visually clearer and can be nested.